# Does starting threads from asyncio is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-asyncio

Is it good to start threads from `loop.run_forever()` in `asyncio`? Is that a good practice?

I also use thread pool inside `asyncio`, I cannot get good speeds with `asyncio` alone that's why I use thread pools.

Does memory will be free after thread pool execution even the `loop.run_forever()` continues to run forever?

Comment: You can start threads from asyncio provided you don't break the rules, such as "don't interact with asyncio from threads other than the one that runs the event loop." In general you shouldn't *need* to start threads, use tools like `run_in_executor` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a new thread from `asyncio` code is not a bug but pretty useless operation.

1. You should control how many threads you have forked already. It is important because keeping in flight a thousand of parallel thread usually is a flag that something is wrong with the program design.
2. Very often you need to get a result of calculations executed in a thread back in asyncio code.
3. Shutdown all active threads on program termination sounds wise, isn't it?

Built-in asyncio `loop.run_in_executor()` with a company of standard thread pool implementation (`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`) solves all problem in very elegant way, please use it.

Comment: Yes iam using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor inside loop.runforever is that a good one?

Comment: If you use `loop.run_in_executor()` with your custom executor instance -- you are correct. Explicit call of executor methods is a sign of API misusage.

Comment: But it does not give good speed but with a 50 threads at a time give much more speed and it can achieved through ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What prevents to to pass your custom `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_size=50)` into `loop.run_in_executor` as a first parameter?

Comment: I use this inside loop.runforever() " with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(50) as executor:"

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Are u sure about that it gives more speed than asyncio but takes lots of cpu but thats not a problem what i need is to finish the tasks as soon as possible